# How to evaluate $\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac1{ar^n+b}$ for non negative a, r and b

Tags: sequences-and-series

I was trying to find the sum of the series of the form:

$$
\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac1{ar^n+b}
$$

For various values of $a,r$ and $b$, where $a$ and $r$ are non-zero.

The value of the sum is pretty straightforward for $b=0$, which is a simple geometric progression.

Can anyone suggest the strategy to be adopted to evaluate such types of sums? I don't think this can be solved via the standard tactics of telescoping sums or differentiating the Taylor expansions of standard functions. Please help.

Edit : To avoid cases where the denominator becomes 0, we shall limit the question to analyze the sum non negative values of a, r and b.

Comment: Have you tried working out when this sum even converges?

Comment: @JackT For b>=0, it can converge only if the absolute value of r is >1.

Comment: @ScipioAemilianus Ok, you might want to include for which values of $a$, $b$, and $r$ you want to consider. For example, are you taking them all positive?

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez Sorry, I wasn't trying to be unnecessarily nit-picky. Of course, this is the only sensible interpretation of the problem, but then the first step of the solution is then to work out when the series converges and I was trying to lead the OP to explicitly give that information

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez Moreover, calculating the sum is also going to be problematic because you need to avoid the case $a r^n + b =0$ for some $n$, so I asked about the parameters being positive because it’s a natural assumption and it rules out this issue

Comment: I think the polygamma function would help. See [here](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/q-PolygammaFunction.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As said in comments, the explicit result involves the [q-polygamma function](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/q-PolygammaFunction.html) which is not the most pleasant do work with

$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac1{a\,r^n+b}=\frac 1a\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac1{r^n+c} \quad \text{with} \quad c=\frac b a$$

$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac1{r^n+c}=\frac{2i\pi+\log \left(c^2\, r \,(r-1)^2 \right)+2\psi _r^{(0)}\left(-\frac{\log (c)+i \pi }{\log (r)}\right)}{2 c \log (r) }$$ But, since the integral is simple
$$\int \frac {dn}{r^n+c}=\frac 1{ c \log (r) }\log \left(\frac{r^n}{r^n+c}\right)$$ we can use the simplest form of Euler-MacLaurin summation formula and assuming $c>0$ and $r>1$ obtain

$$\frac{\log (c+1)}{c \log (r)}+\frac{1}{2 (c+1)}+\frac{\log (r)}{12 (c+1)^2}-\frac{\left(c^2-4 c+1\right) \log ^3(r)}{720 (c+1)^4}+$$
$$\frac{\left(c^4-26 c^3+66 c^2-26 c+1\right) \log ^5(r)}{30240 (c+1)^6}-$$
$$\frac{\left(c^6-120 c^5+1191 c^4-2416 c^3+1191 c^2-120 c+1\right) \log ^7(r)}{1209600 (c+1)^8}$$

Trying for $r=e$ and $c=1$, the above will give
$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac1{e^n+1}\sim \frac{582793}{2150400}+\log (2)=0.9641632706 $$ while
$$\psi _e^{(0)}(-i \pi )+\frac{1}{2}+i \pi +\log (e-1)=0.9641635158$$ corresponding to an absolute error of $2.45\times 10^{-7}$.

For sure, using more terms in the Euler-MacLaurin summation would lead to better and better.

Pushing the expansion to the fifth level
$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac1{e^n+1}\sim \frac{92541215826248513}{341459930972160000}+\log (2)$$ corresponding to an absolute error of $9.62\times 10^{-9}$.